# Tricky situation on Bootstrap upgrade 2.x to 3.x => my layout messed up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media

I'm upgraded my site to newest bootstrap and It's driving me crazy.
Although the window size is the same v1 and v2 of my site are catching different @media sizes! What the???

on the left the V1 of my site with bootstrap 2.0, on the right v2 with latest bootstrap 3.x
[image]

any idea?

ps: since from v3 of bootstrap, the bootstrap-responsive.css is integrated I didn't import this file, but it seems to me normal, is it?

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 has backwards incompatible changes for Bootstrap 2, like giving new names to all grid classes. You cannot do Bootstrap update by just dropping in a new CSS file - you need to rewrite your HTML code also.

Comment: Well did't they make some sort of changelog or porting tutorial? which element changed to what? kinda? :D

Comment: Still...how is it that it catches a different window size?!

Comment: @Michele I don't think it is. It's just that Bootstrap 3 has more media queries than 2, and one of the new ones is being caught where there wasn't anything to be caught before.

Comment: I have an iMac 27'' and I'm in full screen!! It's impossible it doesn't catch the right size!